# Rocket Framework sample does not compile

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I tried to install Rust nightly and compile Rocket's hello_world sample project. I got this error:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `Lifetime`

error[E0599]: no associated item named `Lifetime` found for type `syntax::ast::GenericParam` in the current scope
  --> /Users/azwar/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rocket_codegen-0.3.13/src/decorators/derive_form.rs:30:25
   |
30 |                         GenericParam::Lifetime(ref def) => Some(def),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated item not found in `syntax::ast::GenericParam`
```

I searched this error, but there are no thread or article that explain how to fix that error.

These are my dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.3.13"
rocket_codegen = "0.3.13"
```

I'm using Rust `rust version 1.28.0-nightly (cbc4c8380 2018-06-22)`

Comment: Maybe this should go into bug issue of rocket repository ?

Comment: Like for exemple, https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/671

Comment: Thank you, it was fixed. Sorry for reposting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is [fixed in v0.3.14](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/671#issuecomment-399640910).

Update your `Cargo.toml` to `"0.3.14"`. Then update your crates with `cargo update` or specify the packages directly:

```
cargo update -p rocket_codegen
cargo update -p rocket
```

Comment: So this is not my own error? Ok, thank you for letting me know about it.